# How to light up all LEDs of a 7x5 LED matrix?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to light up all the LEDs of a 7x5 matrix with arduino uno. How can i do so?

Comment: Mark Smith has answered the question you asked.  If you didn't get an answer to what you want to know (and I presume you want to how to turn them on/off under program control) then edit the question to ask what you actually want to know.  Include LED part numbers and/or links, because LED current requirements will affect how best to do this; and how to treat common anode may differ from common cathode, and affects multiplexing if that's needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an Arduino for that, and one will give you no benefit.

Connect all anodes to power, and all cathodes to the appropriate resistors, then ground.

Comment: The first thing I thought of when reading this answer was "I would have answered LEDs are not flammable; add some gasoline, enlight the uno with a blowtorch and then you will be able to light them up"